# (X,$\tau$) is a topological space. E $\subseteq X$. If E is dense in X and X \ E is dense in X, then there are no isolated points in E.

Tags: general-topology

I proceed by contradiction. Then, there exists a point which is isolated. That means that there exists a neighborhood U of that point such that:
$$ U \cap E = \{p\} $$
This means that p $\in$ E. Thus, p is in the closure of E.
But the closure of E equals the closure of $X\setminus E$ because they are both dense in X. If p is in the closure of $X\setminus E$ then for all neighborhood of p we can write that:
$$ V \cap ( X \setminus E ) \neq \emptyset $$
This means that: $$ (V \cap X ) \setminus  E \neq  \emptyset $$
This means that p $\notin$E. But this is a contradiction. 
Is this proof right? I always get to a conclusion but I always struggle to understand if everything that I did is acceptable. 
Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean that there are no isolated points in $E$ or $X$? If it's the latter, then your first step is technically incorrect, but can easily be rectified by doing casework. Also, what do you mean by $(V\cap X)E\neq\emptyset$?

Comment: There are no isolated points in E! Sorry about that, I'll edit.

Comment: I think the statement is false: take $\mathbb{Z}\times \{0,1\}$, then under suitable topology (the one under which the two copies of the same number are indistinguishable) $\mathbb{Z}\times \{0\}$ and $\mathbb{Z}\times \{1\}$ should both be dense, all points being isolated in them.

Comment: Your last expression $(V\cap X)E$ obviously has a typo (because it's meaningless as written) so I can't tell what you meant so I can't tell if you're right.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $X$ is Hausdorff (but $T_1$ would be sufficient).

Let $p\in E$ and let $U$ be an open neighborhood of $p$ (in $X$) with $U\cap E=\{p\}$. By assumption, $U\cap(X\setminus E)\ne\emptyset$.

Let $q\in U\cap(X\setminus E)$; then $U'=U\setminus\{p\}$ is an open neighborhood of $q$, so $U'\cap E\ne\emptyset$: a contradiction.

If the space is not $T_1$ the statement is false: if $X=\{0,1\}$ has the indiscrete topology, both $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ are dense.

Comment: The statement to prove is that if $X$ has a dense,co-dense subset then $X$ has no isolated points. If $X=\{0,1\}$ with the indiscrete topology then $X$ has no isolated points so it does not contradict the statement.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Sorry, but the question is different from what you're saying: it is about isolated points in $E$, not in $X$. In the final example, the set $E=\{0\}$ clearly has an isolated point, but it is dense and $X\setminus E$ is dense as well.

Comment: Sorry . You are right.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet No problem, as you see from the comments to the question, others had the same idea.

Comment: Thanks for the proof @egreg. I have a question: why is $U' \cap E \neq \emptyset $ a contradiction?

Comment: @LudovicoBessi Because, by construction, the intersection is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is wrong and here is the problem: you get to $(V\cap X)\setminus E\neq\emptyset$ for all open neghbourhoods $V$ of $p$. But, $V\cap X = V$, so what you have is that $V\setminus E\neq \emptyset$. This doesn't actually tell you that $p\not\in E$. Why would it? All this tells you is that there are no open neighbourhoods of $p$ completely contained in $E$, which just tells you that $E$ is not open in $X$.

egreg already posted a counterexample to the claim as is. However, it is true that there are no isolated points in $X$. Assume that $p$ is isolated point in $X$. It means that $\{p\}$ is open in $X$. However, if $p\in E$, then there exists open set in $X$ not intersecting $X\setminus E$ (namely $\{p\}$), so $X\setminus E$ is not dense in $X$, and if $p\not\in E$, the same argument says that $E$ is not dense in $X$.